# Scrabble Sort Of

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How can I make a code that makes it so that each letter in the alphabet is assigned to a Scrabble Score? For example a= 1 point, b= 3 point, c= 3 points. Then if I have String "abc" the value of the String would be 7 points. The idea I have so far is these two arrays:

```
private int[] Points= {1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10};
private String Letters[] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashMap`.  The `get()` part will return 3. The `String` can also be changed to a char with `Character`.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("a", 1);
    map.put("b", 3);

    map.get("b");
```

Answer (score 1):

im not sure what language that is that you are writing in but i can help you with the general concept. you could use an object(javascript) or dictionairy(python) or hash(ruby) and assign each letter a score value like so

```
scores = {
    "a":1,
    "b":3,
    "c":3
}
```

and so on until z
then to find the score you could do something like this ill use a javascript example but its very similar in other languages by using a loop

```
var word = abc;
var score = 0;
for(i=0;i<word.length;i++){
    result += scores[i]
}
```

Comment: The language (Java) is in the list of tags for the question.

Comment: what type of object is scores? is it an array of int or string?

Comment: scores is a just a plain object consisting of key : value pairs it is not an int string nor array im not 100% sure of its name but i think its known as an object in javascript, a dictionairy in python and a hash in ruby and associative array in php.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a hashmap where the key is a char (the letter) and the value is an int (the score).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
private static final Map<Character, Integer> letterValues = new HashMap<>();

static {
    letterValues.put('a', 1);
    letterValues.put('b', 3);
    // ...
    letterValues.put('z', 10);
}
```

And then make a method like:

```
public int getWordValue(String word) {
    int value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        value += letterValue.get(word.charAt(i));
    }
    return value;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do it with a switch:

```
public int getLetterValue(char letter) {
    switch(letter) {
    case 'a': return 1;
    case 'b': return 3;
    // ...
    case 'z': return 10;
    default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void display() {
    int[] points = { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };
    String letters[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
            "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

    //Holding alphabet's corresponding value in a map
    Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        tempMap.put(letters[i], points[i]);
    }

    //Test Data
    String test = "abc";
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        sum += tempMap.get(test.charAt(i)+"");//making character to string
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

}
```